# color averaging in opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to compute the average color of a region of a RGB image. The interested region of the image is represented by a mask. I used `cvAvg` function in opencv, but somehow I am not able to do it right.
I used the following code:

```
//Prepare the mask
CvMat*regionMask = cvCreateMat(inImage->height, inImage->width, CV_8UC1);
cvZero(regionMask);
uchar* maskData = regionMask->data.ptr;
if(some_cond)
   maskData[(p.y)*inImage->width + p.x] = 1;

//Compute average and set the output region
cvSet(outImage, cvAvg(inImage, regionMask), regionMask);
```

This is the result:

First image is input, then mask and then the output image.

[image: Input Image]  [image: Mask]   [image: Output]

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you want to find average **color** how can output be **image**???

Comment: I want to replace the entire region with its average color. What is wrong with it?

Comment: the region represented by mask. For that region, I wan to calculate the average color, and assign the same average color to all pixels in that region.

Comment: So the output image will be one-color, right?

Comment: Yes, I am concerned about the masked region only. Rest of the image may be copied from source or just be background pixels (black in my example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I replaced the statement 
`maskData[(p.y)*inImage->width + p.x] = 1;` with `maskData[(p.y)*maskData->step + p.x] = 1;` and it works fine now.

Thanks.